# how to read user date selection off an existing calendar

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm learning web scraping and I need the webdriver to wait until the user selects a start date and end date off an existing calendar from [here](https://booking.com) and read it so I can process the availabilities in that given period. I hope somebody can help me!

here's the part of the code:

```
tables = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@role='grid']")))
table_first_month = tables[0].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")
all_dates = table_first_month.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@role='gridcell']")

for date in all_dates:
    date_span = date.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "span")
    aria_label_span = date_span.get_attribute("aria-label")
    print(aria_label_span) 
    #userStartDate = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((this is where i need help)))
    if aria_label_span == str(userStartDate):
        date_span.click()
        time.sleep(4)
        break
```

this code gets the avalaibale dates in calendar for the shown two months and verifies the condition that the given date (the user will select) exists with the help of this function

```
def press_right_arrow_until_date_is_found(date):
    # get the text of the initial calendar
    current_calendar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]").text
    # while the date does not appear in the calendar view press right arrow until it does
    while(date_formater(date) not in current_calendar):
        right_arrow = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
            "//button[@class='fc63351294 a822bdf511 e3c025e003 fa565176a8 cfb238afa1 ae1678b153 c9fa5fc96d be298b15fa']")
        right_arrow.click()
        current_calendar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
            "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]").text
```

Comment: So the user is inputing while selenium is running? Could you use an input and wait for a user to tell selenium to continue?

Comment: What you are asking for is not a good use of Selenium. The point of automation is to do things without user intervention. If you are going to wait for a user to enter information, what's the point? Maybe you are new and looking for a scenario to automate to practice coding? If so, I would suggest you look at the samples pages on http://the-internet.herokuapp.com and invent some scenarios to automate there.

Comment: @AaronCloud yes exactly, selenium must pause until a user selects two dates, i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: @JeffC well if there's `element_to_be_clickable` option in python selenium I think it's possible to have the user intervention right?

Comment: So you added an input on the terminal? It should hit that and will wait for the users input. You could also put a listen for a certain keypress as well.

Comment: @LbS It's code so you can do just about anything you want. My point is that it's not a good idea. You are trying to have a script do some things, wait for the user to do something, and then have the script do some more things. What you are describing is like trying to add functionality to a website in an extremely clunky way.

Comment: @LbS `element_to_be_clickable` is a Selenium method to wait for the element you want to click to be clickable. It doesn't have anything to do with user intervention... it's the exact opposite. It's a method to wait the minimum amount of time possible before continuing the script.

Comment: @LbS If you are going to proceed with what you asked, the better way to do it would be to put the user preferences in a file, read from that file in the script, put those preferences in the page, and then scrape the page. That way you don't have to wait for the user while the script is running.